# How to benchmark RAM memory with a Linux Distro?

Tags: ram, benchmark

I' ve just bought new RAM and I'd like to benchmark and compare with my old. How can I do that?

Comment: http://www.overclock.net/t/562717/ram-benchmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package hardinfo (http://sourceforge.net/projects/hardinfo.berlios/) is a pretty decent system benchmarker with a nice GUI. The simplest way to compare the two would be to benchmark one save the results and then compare it to your benchmarking of the other.

EDIT

Depending on your distro, you may already have hardinfo installed, for example on Lubuntu it is called "System Profiler and Benchmark".

Comment: Oops site does not exist...

Comment: How benchmark(s) is(are) called? I only see here CPU ones, but perhaps do I need to install an additional package?

Comment: Project seems to live on GitHub now: https://github.com/lpereira/hardinfo

Answer (score 2):

Consider that in today's machines one real memory access is worth a few hundred instructions, the benchmark results probably depend much more on CPU and cache behaviour than RAM speed. And the speed might be limited by the motherboard's handling of RAM too.

Comment: But that's the point of RAM benchmarks, they should be written in such a way, that CPU cache would affect them little, or not at all. Otherwise it indeed would test cache speed instead of RAM.